# Is there a limit on the number of key-value pairs emitted by a mapper?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In a Map Reduce program, is there an upper limit on the number of key-value pairs that can be emitted by a single mapper?

I am interested in both Hadoop 1.x and 2.x. I have googled it and could not find any answers, or any mention of it at all.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that there is a limit other than the number of key-value pairs that can fit in your storage space.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no limit** on the number of key value pairs emitted by a single mapper.


The mapper keeps generating  output which are written to a buffer. The size of this buffer is determined by configuration *mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb* [Default: 256MB(CDH), 100MB(Source Code)].
Whenever this buffer occupancy reaches *mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent* [Def: 0.8] of the capacity, the buffer content is spilled (non blocking process) to local disk - spill file.